# update state in react if the 2 condition is true on a button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
     const multiple = option.map( item => {
     return <button key={item.id} className={item.isSelected ? "bg" : 
    "option"} onClick={() => handleClick(item.id , item.isSelected)}> 
     {item.text}</button>
  })

    function handleClick(id){
    setOption( prevValue => prevValue.map( (item) => {
      if( item.id === id && **item.isSelected** ){
         return { ...item , isSelected:!item.isSelected}
      }else{
         return item
      }
   }))
```

i have have 4 objects in an array and each object has property of isSelected
**i need my function exuctes only all is isSelected property  is true**

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please share your other code where you trigger the ```onClick``` on the button and send the ```id```?

Comment: code edited @tehila

Comment: You call the `handleClick` function with two parameters, while the function has only one parameter.

Comment: That's right, you forgot to accept the ```item.isSelected``` in the ```handleClick``` function too.

Comment: You have an array of objects and every object has an id and isSelected property. You map the array and show a button and other elements on the UI for every item {object} of the array. Now when the user clicks on the button you want to call the handleClick function. handleClick function is responsible for updating the state if the condition item.id === id && item.isSelected is true. is It your question? @MohammedSabir

Comment: yes , i have 4 objects . so i have 4 isSelected property  so i need the function to run. when all the isSelected is true . @arifurRahaman

Comment: If you want to check all isSelected is true or not then the code will be like:  
const isAllPassed = state.every((item) => item.isSelected === "true");
here isAllPassed value will be true if the all isSelected is true otherwise isAllPassed value will be false.

Answer (score 0):

I clearly don't know your problem but if you want to run the function only if all the object's isSelected is true then try this.

```
function handleClick(id, selected){
        let newArr = options.filter((val)=> {
         return val.isSelected === false;
        })
        if(newArr.length === 0){
            setOption( prevValue => prevValue.map( (item) => {
            if( item.id === id && item.isSelected ){
            return { ...item , isSelected:!item.isSelected}
    }
    }
```